# How can I orchestrate the startup and re-starting of two interdependent docker containers?

Tags: docker

I'm using a docker container as a data-only volume for my Jenkins CI server.  As such, to start the Jenkins service, I need to run two consecutive commands:

```
docker run --name=jenkins_data -v /path/to/volume/:/var/jenkins_home busybox
docker run -d --name=jenkins_server -p 8081:8080 --volumes-from jenkins_data --restart="always" jenkins
```

How can I coordinate these two containers such that they auto-(re)start?  How do I make sure that the `jenkins_data` container is running prior to launching `jenkins_server`?

I tried setting `--restart="always"` for the `jenkins_data` container, but since it exits immediately after the first `docker run` command, it gets re-run every few seconds or so.

Essentially, I'd like to treat both containers as a service that automatically starts when the server boots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you're not using a data-only container.  Since you're actually mounting a host volume, your data container really isn't buying you anything: you could just as easily replace `--volumes-from` on the second container with the `-v /path/to/volume:/var/jenkins_home` command line option.

Second, you don't need to "start" a data container in order to reference it in `--volumes-from`.  Consider:

```
docker run --name mydata -v /data busybox true
```

This container exits immediately (because we're just running `true`).  But now I can do this:

```
docker run --volumes-from mydata -it busybox sh
```

And I can see the `/data` volume from the `mydata` container:

```
/ # df -P |grep data
/dev/mapper/tank-docker  10190136    357972   9815780   4% /data
```

This means that you don't actually need to worry about starting up multiple containers.  As long as your data container *exists*, you can reference it in the `--volumes-from` in the Jenkins container.

Comment: I see!  Thanks for clearing up my misconceptions -- this makes much more sense now.